# $request->isMethod('POST') vs @Method("POST") Symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony

what is the difference between **$request->isMethod('POST')** and
 **@Method("POST")** annotation for implementing REST API services?

Do I need to check if method is POST while I have **@Method("POST")**
annotation ?

```
* @Rest\Route("device/{userId}")
* @Method('POST')
* @param int $userId
* @param Request $request
* @return JsonResponse
*/
public function newAction(Request $request, int $userId) {
   if ($request->isMethod('POST')) { // is it necessary ?!
       ...
   }       
 ...        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary. Method declaration in the annotation makes it one of the criteria used for matching the route. If you try to send a request to this URL with a different method, it will not be matched by the router, so there's zero chance that this action gets called with any method other than `POST`.